# In what order should you insert a set of known keys into a B-Tree to get minimal height?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

Given a fixed number of keys or values(stored either in array or in some data structure) and order of b-tree, can we determine the sequence of inserting keys that would generate a space efficient b-tree.

To illustrate, consider b-tree of order 3. Let the keys be {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.  Inserting elements into tree in the following order

```
for(int i=1 ;i<8; ++i)
{
 tree.push(i);  
}
```

would create a tree like this

```
        4
     2      6
   1  3   5   7
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

But inserting elements in this way

```
flag = true;
for(int i=1,j=7; i<8; ++i,--j)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        tree.push(i);
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        tree.push(j);
        flag = true;
    }   
}
```

creates a tree like this

```
    3 5
1 2  4  6 7
```

where we can see there is decrease in level.

So is there a particular way to determine sequence of insertion which would reduce space consumption?

Comment: Wouldn't for(int i=1 ;i<8; ++i) { tree.push(i); } give you a linked list (each node having a right child only) instead of what you show?

Answer (score 7):

The following trick should work for most ordered search trees, assuming the data to insert are the integers `1..n`.

Consider the binary representation of your integer keys - for 1..7 (with dots for zeros) that's...

```
Bit : 210
  1 : ..1
  2 : .1.
  3 : .11
  4 : 1..
  5 : 1.1
  6 : 11.
  7 : 111
```

Bit 2 changes least often, Bit 0 changes most often. That's the opposite of what we want, so what if we reverse the order of those bits, then sort our keys in order of this bit-reversed value...

```
Bit : 210    Rev
  4 : 1.. -> ..1 : 1
  ------------------
  2 : .1. -> .1. : 2
  6 : 11. -> .11 : 3
  ------------------
  1 : ..1 -> 1.. : 4
  5 : 1.1 -> 1.1 : 5
  3 : .11 -> 11. : 6
  7 : 111 -> 111 : 7
```

It's easiest to explain this in terms of an unbalanced binary search tree, growing by adding leaves. The first item is dead centre - it's exactly the item we want for the root. Then we add the keys for the next layer down. Finally, we add the leaf layer. At every step, the tree is as balanced as it can be, so even if you happen to be building an AVL or red-black balanced tree, the rebalancing logic should never be invoked.

[**EDIT** I just realised you don't need to sort the data based on those bit-reversed values in order to access the keys in that order. The trick to that is to notice that bit-reversing is its own inverse. As well as mapping keys to positions, it maps positions to keys. So if you loop through from 1..n, you can use this bit-reversed value to decide which item to insert next - for the first insert use the 4th item, for the second insert use the second item and so on. One complication - you have to round n upwards to one less than a power of two (7 is OK, but use 15 instead of 8) and you have to bounds-check the bit-reversed values. The reason is that bit-reversing can move some in-bounds positions out-of-bounds and visa versa.]

Actually, for a red-black tree *some* rebalancing logic will be invoked, but it should just be re-colouring nodes - not rearranging them. However, I haven't double checked, so don't rely on this claim.

For a B tree, the height of the tree grows by adding a new root. Proving this works is, therefore, a little awkward (and it may require a more careful node-splitting than a B tree normally requires) but the basic idea is the same. Although rebalancing occurs, it occurs in a balanced way because of the order of inserts.

This can be generalised for any set of known-in-advance keys because, once the keys are sorted, you can assign suitable indexes based on that sorted order.

---

**WARNING** - This isn't an efficient way to construct a perfectly balanced tree from known already-sorted data.

If you have your data already sorted, and know it's size, you can build a perfectly balanced tree in O(n) time. Here's some pseudocode...

```
if size is zero, return null
from the size, decide which index should be the (subtree) root
recurse for the left subtree, giving that index as the size (assuming 0 is a valid index)
take the next item to build the (subtree) root
recurse for the right subtree, giving (size - (index + 1)) as the size
add the left and right subtree results as the child pointers
return the new (subtree) root
```

Basically, this decides the structure of the tree based on the size and traverses that structure, building the actual nodes along the way. It shouldn't be too hard to adapt it for B Trees.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I would add elements to b-tree.

Thanks to Steve314, for giving me the start with binary representation,

Given are n elements to add, in order. We have to add it to m-order b-tree. Take their indexes (1...n) and convert it to radix m. The main idea of this insertion is to insert number with highest m-radix bit currently and keep it above the lesser m-radix numbers added in the tree despite splitting of nodes.

1,2,3.. are indexes so you actually insert the numbers they point to.

```
For example, order-4 tree
      4       8         12           highest radix bit numbers
1,2,3   5,6,7   9,10,11    13,14,15
```

Now depending on order median can be:

- order is even -> number of keys are odd -> median is middle (mid median)
- order is odd -> number of keys are even -> left median or right median

The choice of median (left/right) to be promoted will decide the order in which I should insert elements. This has to be fixed for the b-tree.

I add elements to trees in buckets. First I add bucket elements then on completion next bucket in order. Buckets can be easily created if  median is known, bucket size is order m.

```
I take left median for promotion. Choosing bucket for insertion.
    |  4     |  8      |   12       |    
1,2,|3   5,6,|7   9,10,|11    13,14,|15  
        3       2          1             Order to insert buckets.
```

- For left-median choice I insert buckets to the tree starting from right side, for right median choice I insert buckets from left side. Choosing left-median we insert median first, then elements to left of it first then rest of the numbers in the bucket.

Example

```
Bucket median first
12,
Add elements to left
11,12,
Then after all elements inserted it looks like,
|   12       | 
|11    13,14,| 
Then I choose the bucket left to it. And repeat the same process.
Median
     12        
8,11    13,14, 
Add elements to left first
       12        
7,8,11    13,14, 
Adding rest
  8      |   12        
7   9,10,|11    13,14, 
Similarly keep adding all the numbers,
  4     |  8      |   12        
3   5,6,|7   9,10,|11    13,14, 
At the end add numbers left out from buckets.
    |  4     |  8      |   12       |   
1,2,|3   5,6,|7   9,10,|11    13,14,|15
```

- For mid-median (even order b-trees) you simply insert the median and then all the numbers in the bucket.
- For right-median I add buckets from the left. For elements within the bucket I first insert median then right elements and then left elements.

Here we are adding the highest m-radix numbers, and in the process I added numbers with immediate lesser m-radix bit, making sure the highest m-radix numbers stay at top. Here I have only two levels, for more levels I repeat the same process in descending order of radix bits.

Last case is when remaining elements are of same radix-bit and there is no numbers with lesser radix-bit, then simply insert them and finish the procedure.

I would give an example for 3 levels, but it is too long to show. So please try with other parameters and tell if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, all trees exhibit their worst case scenario running times, and require rigid balancing techniques when data is entered in increasing order like that. Binary trees quickly turn into linked lists, etc.

For typical B-Tree use cases (databases, filesystems, etc), you can typically count on your data naturally being more distributed, producing a tree more like your second example.

Though if it is really a concern, you could hash each key, guaranteeing a wider distribution of values.

```
for( i=1; i<8; ++i )
    tree.push(hash(i));
```

Comment: I think the question is not so much "can we always avoid the worst-case" as much as "if I know the keys in advance, can I find the ideal insertion order?"

Answer (score 1):

To build a particular B-tree using Insert() as a black box, work backward. Given a nonempty B-tree, find a node with more than the minimum number of children that's as close to the leaves as possible. The root is considered to have minimum 0, so a node with the minimum number of children always exists. Delete a value from this node to be prepended to the list of Insert() calls. Work toward the leaves, merging subtrees.

For example, given the 2-3 tree

```
       8
   4       c
 2   6   a   e
1 3 5 7 9 b d f,
```

we choose 8 and do merges to obtain the predecessor

```
   4      c
 2   6  a   e
1 3 5 79 b d f.
```

Then we choose 9.

```
   4     c
 2   6 a   e
1 3 5 7 b d f
```

Then a.

```
    4    c
 2    6    e
1 3  5 7b d f
```

Then b.

```
   4   c
 2   6   e
1 3 5 7 d f
```

Then c.

```
   4
 2   6  e
1 3 5 7d f
```

Et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a particular way to determine sequence of insertion which would reduce **space consumption**?

**Edit note**: since the question was quite interesting, I try to improve my answer with a bit of Haskell.

Let `k` be the Knuth order of the B-Tree and `list` a list of keys

The minimization of space consumption has a trivial solution:

```hs
-- won't use point free notation to ease haskell newbies
trivial k list = concat $ reverse $ chunksOf (k-1) $ sort list
```

Such algorithm will **efficiently** produce a **time-inefficient** B-Tree, unbalanced on the left but with minimal **space** consumption.

A lot of non trivial solutions exist that are less efficient to produce but show better lookup performance (lower height/depth). As you know, **it's all about trade-offs**!

A simple algorithm that minimizes both the B-Tree depth and the space consumption (but it doesn't **minimize** lookup performance!), is the following

```hs
-- Sort the list in increasing order and call sortByBTreeSpaceConsumption 
-- with the result
smart k list = sortByBTreeSpaceConsumption k $ sort list

-- Sort list so that inserting in a B-Tree with Knuth order = k 
-- will produce a B-Tree  with minimal space consumption minimal depth 
-- (but not best performance)
sortByBTreeSpaceConsumption :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
sortByBTreeSpaceConsumption _ [] = []
sortByBTreeSpaceConsumption k list
    | k - 1 >= numOfItems = list  -- this will be a leaf
    | otherwise = heads ++ tails ++ sortByBTreeSpaceConsumption k remainder
    where requiredLayers = minNumberOfLayersToArrange k list
          numOfItems = length list
          capacityOfInnerLayers = capacityOfBTree k $ requiredLayers - 1
          blockSize = capacityOfInnerLayers + 1 
          blocks = chunksOf blockSize balanced
          heads = map last blocks
          tails = concat $ map (sortByBTreeSpaceConsumption k . init) blocks
          balanced = take (numOfItems - (mod numOfItems blockSize)) list
          remainder = drop (numOfItems - (mod numOfItems blockSize)) list

-- Capacity of a layer n in a B-Tree with Knuth order = k
layerCapacity k 0 = k - 1
layerCapacity k n = k * layerCapacity k (n - 1)

-- Infinite list of capacities of layers in a B-Tree with Knuth order = k
capacitiesOfLayers k = map (layerCapacity k) [0..]

-- Capacity of a B-Tree with Knut order = k and l layers
capacityOfBTree k l = sum $ take l $ capacitiesOfLayers k

-- Infinite list of capacities of B-Trees with Knuth order = k 
-- as the number of layers increases
capacitiesOfBTree k = map (capacityOfBTree k) [1..]

-- compute the minimum number of layers in a B-Tree of Knuth order k 
-- required to store the items in list
minNumberOfLayersToArrange k list = 1 + f k
    where numOfItems = length list
          f = length . takeWhile (< numOfItems) . capacitiesOfBTree
```

With this `smart` function given a `list = [21, 18, 16, 9, 12, 7, 6, 5, 1, 2]` and a B-Tree with knuth order = 3 we should obtain `[18, 5, 9, 1, 2, 6, 7, 12, 16, 21]` with a resulting B-Tree like

```
              [18, 21]
             /
      [5 , 9]
     /   |   \
 [1,2] [6,7] [12, 16]
```

Obviously this is suboptimal from a performance point of view, but should be acceptable, since obtaining a better one (like the following) would be far more expensive (computationally and economically):

```
          [7 , 16]
         /   |   \
     [5,6] [9,12] [18, 21]
    /
[1,2]
```

If you want to run it, compile the previous code in a Main.hs file and compile it with ghc after prepending

```hs
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.List.Split
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let knuthOrder = read $ head args
    let keys = (map read $ tail args) :: [Int]
    putStr "smart: "
    putStrLn $ show $ smart knuthOrder keys
    putStr "trivial: "
    putStrLn $ show $ trivial knuthOrder keys
```